# Can fallen characters be revived in Classic Mode?

Tags: fire-emblem-warriors

When playing Fire Emblem Warriors in "Classic Mode", it's possible for characters to be defeated and incapacitated, just like in the main series. Is there a way to bring them back without switching the game to "Casual Mode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, once you get 10 of Anna's Mementos, the Temple adds the "Revive" option.  This costs 300,000G and 10 gold materials which is a hefty price but better than not being able to do it at all.

Comment: Duuuuuude. That's a lot of work, but I s'pose it's better than nothing. Thanks! (And thanks for being so specific. I've got about 7 or 8 as of this posting, so I'm well on my way.)