# Fire Emblem Warriors: Classic Mode vs. Casual Mode Incentives

Tags: fire-emblem-warriors

I just started Fire Emblem Warriors for the Nintendo Switch and came across the selection to choose between Casual Mode and Classic Mode. The game described the two modes as being able to revive allies vs not being able to revive them until a certain point, but it did not seem to mention any sort of reason or incentive to play on classic mode over casual mode.

I've searched the issue a bit and saw places like [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204209-fire-emblem-warriors/75900740) where they gloss over the issue, but don't seem to come to any conclusion. There's also a post on Arqade [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320101/can-fallen-characters-be-revived-in-classic-mode) asking whether or not allies can be resurrected, but that doesn't really answer the question either.

So, is there any reward or incentive for playing on Classic Mode instead of Casual Mode in Fire Emblem Warriors?

Comment: For many games, there is no incentive in picking "Normal" over "Easy". Might not be the case here, but this follows the other FE games' patterns of introducing a more beginner-friendly mode.

Comment: At least for the difficulty there is a in-game monetary incentive, 1.5x gold every battle with hard difficulty. So that’s what got me wondering about the classic vs casual.